# EmailMessage Storage Issue

Tags: salesforcedx, data-loader, relationships, service-cloud-console, emailmessage

Currently we are facing storage issue in org production. It is reached to 90%. Most of the storage is consumed by emailmessage. We looking different solutions. We are planning to extract the emailmessage records from past year and store it in local drive after storing in local we are going to do delete those records, once the storage is increased again we are planning to insert them back in to salesforce. Here my concern is about the relations between emailmessage and case,task,etc deleting and again inserting will impact these or not

Comment: If your storage size gets increased, is there any reason to migrate the data out of Salesforce?

Comment: If you can afford to archive such records in the first place, why migrate them back to Salesforce? You will be requesting another storage increase before you know it, I suggest a long term archiving solution if the records are to be accessed by Salesforce users from custom/standard object records.

Comment: Actually we don't have much time that's why for the short term we come up with this in the long term we working on the archive solution.Migrating back because client wants the data.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually related to HTML emails. When you send an HTML email from salesforce, it stores both the HTML code and the text version of that email. 
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000193871&type=1

So while it may seem like a small number of emails, it consumes your org storage quickly. One option is to go to text-only email templates (which is usually not an option for customer-facing emails). If you expect this to continually be a problem, it may be worth considering an email marketing tool like Pardot or Marketing Cloud.

As far as cleaning up the existing storage, you have to delete the email messages altogether, not just delete the HTML part (i tried that a few times...).

You can do a manual process by downloading the data, uploading a few key fields as completed events, and then delete the original email messages.

I hope the above information helps you.

Thanks.